# jMagick on Windows giving error

Tags: makefile, nmake, jmagick

```
C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\jmagick-master\src>nmake -f Makefile.all ALL

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24234.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Could Not Find C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\jmagick-master\obj\magick\jmagick.obj
Could Not Find C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\jmagick-master\obj\magick\magick_Magick.obj
Could Not Find C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\jmagick-master\obj\magick\magick_MontageInfo.obj
Could Not Find C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\jmagick-master\obj\magick\magick_DrawInfo.obj
Could Not Find C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\jmagick-master\obj\magick\magick_ImageInfo.obj
Could Not Find C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\jmagick-master\obj\magick\magick_MagickImage.obj
Could Not Find C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\jmagick-master\obj\magick\magick_PixelPacket.obj
Could Not Find C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\jmagick-master\obj\magick\magick_QuantizeInfo.obj
Could Not Find C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\jmagick-master\lib\jmagick.dll
Could Not Find C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\jmagick-master\lib\jmagick.exp
Could Not Find C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\jmagick-master\lib\jmagick.lib
        mkdir "..\lib"
A subdirectory or file ..\lib already exists.
        mkdir "..\obj\magick"
A subdirectory or file ..\obj\magick already exists.
        mkdir "..\generated"
A subdirectory or file ..\generated already exists.
        mkdir "..\doc"
A subdirectory or file ..\doc already exists.
        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\javac" -target 1.5 -d ..\classes -classpath ..\src\magick -sourcepath ..\src\magick ..\src\magick\ClassType.java ..\src\magick\ColorspaceType.java ..\src\magick\CompositeOperator.java ..\src\magick\CompressionType.java ..\src\magick\DecorationType.java ..\src\magick\DrawInfo.java ..\src\magick\ExceptionType.java ..\src\magick\FilterType.java ..\src\magick\GeometryFlags.java ..\src\magick\GravityType.java ..\src\magick\ImageInfo.java ..\src\magick\ImageMagick.java ..\src\magick\ImageType.java ..\src\magick\InterlaceType.java ..\src\magick\InterpolatePixelMethod.java ..\src\magick\Magick.java ..\src\magick\MagickApiException.java ..\src\magick\MagickException.java ..\src\magick\MagickImage.java ..\src\magick\MagickInfo.java ..\src\magick\MagickLoader.java ..\src\magick\MagickProducer.java ..\src\magick\MapMode.java ..\src\magick\MontageInfo.java ..\src\magick\MontageMode.java ..\src\magick\NoiseType.java ..\src\magick\PaintMethod.java ..\src\magick\PixelPacket.java ..\src\magick\PreviewType.java ..\src\magick\PrimitiveType.java ..\src\magick\ProfileInfo.java ..\src\magick\QuantizeInfo.java ..\src\magick\QuantumTypes.java ..\src\magick\RenderingIntent.java ..\src\magick\ResolutionType.java ..\src\magick\SegmentInfo.java ..\src\magick\StorageType.java ..\src\magick\TimerState.java ..\src\magick\TypeMetric.java ..\src\magick\util\DisplayImageMetaData.java ..\src\magick\util\DisplayIPTCData.java ..\src\magick\util\MagickCanvas.java ..\src\magick\util\MagickViewer.java ..\src\magick\util\MagickWindow.java
javac: directory not found: ..\classes
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\javac.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Trying to make jmagick, using this MakeFile [Source](https://github.com/techblue/jmagick/files/1977743/Makefile.all.txt)

I am trying to use nmake to compile my C and JAVA files.
I have installed VCode and VC++.

I have observed I cannot create object file(for C files) as cl gives me jni.h not found.
I do not why the error mentioned above along with "javac directory error" seems to occur.